# Python scripts runs from PythonWin but not ArcCatalog (ArcGIS 10)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arccatalog, pythonwin

I add a field to the target FeatureClass it is not present, via arcpy.AddField_management(...).  Works fine from PythonWin, but the AddField call fails when the script is run from ArcCatalog.  I have this exception catch code:

```
except Exception as ErrorDesc:
    Errors = "TRUE"
    arcpy.AddMessage("An unknown error occurred:")
    arcpy.AddMessage(ErrorDesc.message)
```

But the error I get is at the end of this output:

```
Getting list of fields.
Adding PC field to target.
An unknown error occurred:
Object: Tool or environment <摁䙤敩摬浟湡条浥湥t> not found
```

And that Mandarin text - is that unicode being mangled?

Comment: Are you using a featureset or a featureclass?

Comment: If you're running this in the python window, give this a try to see if you can get a real error message (instead of the `Exception` method: `print arcpy.GetMessages()`

Comment: Running stand-alone in a python window there is no error - that's the consternation of it.  The target is a FeatureClass.

Comment: I think you need to refer to a featureset

Comment: Have you seen this discussion forum thread?  http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/3727-object-tool-or-environment-lt-repairgeometry-gt-not-found It may or may not be relevant.

Comment: It would really help to include the code that is being run as well as the error code being generated.

Comment: if "PC" not in fields:
  # Process: Add Field PC...
  arcpy.AddMessage("Adding PC field to target.")
  arcpy.AddField_management(siteFC, "PC", "SHORT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

Comment: I had looked at the forum topic mentioned above but could not see relevancy.  My environment is that I am RDP'ing in to a VPC instance on Amazon and running there.  I can connect to the target database since I first get the list of field names to see if "PC" is there; if not, we get to this code where I try to add it.

And what's with the Chinese message anyway?  Maybe the code is routing to China and getting an error there.

Comment: Well, it's definitely something to do with the ArcCatalog runtime environment.  The same tool runs fine through ArcCatalog on a different test box.  Wish I knew how to fix this box, though...

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue here, with some chinese random garble (which looks like some junk from memory):

In my case I load a custom toolbox. When I try to execute a tool from this tbx from my script, I got this in ArcMap 10, SP5:

```
Tool or environment <剉偁潔卅䥒敖瑣牯卟慴潴汩䥇呓潯獬> not found
```

When running the script from my IDE, or from a terminal window, it works fine.

What I did was to add some additional code to show the contents of the toolbox I just loaded:

```
toolbox_file = 'C:\Users\path\to\MyTools.tbx'
arcpy.AddMessage('Importing toolbox: ' + toolbox_file)
tbx = arcpy.ImportToolbox(toolbox_file)
if tbx is None:
    arcpy.AddError("Toolbox is null")
else:
    arcpy.AddMessage("debug: listing tools")
    tools = arcpy.ListTools("*MyGISTools*")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Number of tools found: %i" % len(tools))
    for tool in tools:
        arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.Usage(tool))
```

In the IDE and the terminal I got a list of all the tools with their parameters, as expected.

However, in ArcMap, I got a bunch of

```
Method ToESRIRasterScript_MyGisTools not found. Choices: Method ToESRIRasterScript_MyGisTools not unique, please use ToolboxName_ToolName
Method ToIRAPVectorScript_MyGisTools not found. Choices: Method ToIRAPVectorScript_MyGisTools not unique, please use ToolboxName_ToolName.
Method ToESRIVectorScript_MyGisTools not found. Choices: Method ToESRIVectorScript_MyGisTools not unique, please use ToolboxName_ToolName.
Method PrepareIRAPforInput_MyGisTools not found. Choices: Method PrepareIRAPforInput_MyGisTools not unique, please use ToolboxName_ToolName.
```

This seemed to indicate that something was duplicated. When I removed my toolbox from ArcToolbox, and re-ran it from the Catalog window, it all worked just fine.